# Azure Indoor Maps not rendering

Tags: azure-maps

Trying to create floor plan upload to azure indoor maps. It is uploaded using postman and got the tilesetid but when I provide tilesetid in the Azure Indoor maps sample, it is not rendering the image in html file. When I use sample zip file provided by azure it is working fine.

Following the article as shown in [Azure Indoor Maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-use-indoor-module)
[image]

**Autocad settings**

[image]

Below is the manifest file

```
{
    "version": "1.1",
    "directoryInfo": {
        "name": "Digital Twins Testing Building",
        "streetAddress": "Contoso Way",
        "unit": "1",
        "locality": "Eastside",
        "postalCode": "00000", 
        "adminDivisions": [
            "Contoso City",
            "Contoso State",
            "United States"
        ],
        "hoursOfOperation": "Mo-Fr 08:00-17:00 open",
        "phone": "1 (425) 555-1234",
        "website": "www.contoso.com",
        "nonPublic": false,
        "anchorLatitude": 33.44277,
        "anchorLongitude": -112.072754,
        "anchorHeightAboveSeaLevel": 1000,
        "defaultLevelVerticalExtent": 2
    },
    "buildingLevels": {
        "levels": [{
            "levelName": "Ground Level",
            "ordinal": 0,
            "verticalExtent": 5,
            "filename": "./GroundLevelFloorPlan.dwg"
        }]
    },
    "georeference": {
        "lat": 33.44277,
        "lon": -112.072754,
        "angle": 0
    },
    "dwgLayers": {
        "exterior": [
            "exterior"
        ],
        "unit": [
            "unit"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the manifest, I see you expressed loading only exterior and unit, and didn't pass the label layer which is what brings labels and let you add more properties for the units (or zones). If you don't see the map, I would suggest checking the conversion results (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-maps/drawing-error-visualizer)) which is always a good practice. Another good way to troubleshoot is review the content in the dataset via WFS [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/maps/wfs), for example units via https://atlas.microsoft.com/wfs/datasets//collections/unit/items?api-version=1.0&subscription-key={{subcriptionkey}}